# Add a Javascript function to a Dom element

Tags: javascript

I created a button element and added a click event but the click event never fires and so the function `deleteFile` is never called.

Here is my code:

```
let innerButtonDiv = document.getElementById("fi");
var innerButtonDelete = document.createElement("button");
innerButtonDelete.innerText = "Del";
innerButtonDelete.onclick = 'deleteFile("f")';
innerButtonDiv.appendChild(innerButtonDelete);
```

What is wrong and how can I do it the correct way so the function `deleteFile` gets called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"onclick" accepts a function. Try this:

```
let innerButtonDiv = document.getElementById("fi");
var innerButtonDelete = document.createElement("button");
innerButtonDelete.innerText = "Del";
innerButtonDelete.onclick = () => deleteFile('f');
innerButtonDiv.appendChild(innerButtonDelete);
```

Answer (score 2):

A click is an event that can not be assigned as an attribute.

Attach a listener and use a proper syntax like this-

```
innerButtonDelete.addEventListener('click', () => {
  deleteFile("f")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let innerButtonDiv = document.getElementById("fi");
var innerButtonDelete = document.createElement("button");
innerButtonDelete.innerText = "Del";
innerButtonDiv.appendChild(innerButtonDelete);
innerButtonDelete.addEventListener("click", () => deleteFile("f"))
```

Comment: and how to add the function with a variable?? like this var g = "j"; deleteFile(g)